# Método estático chamando um objeto

Tags: php, classes, métodos-estáticos

Porque o PHP permite eu usar assim, conforme abaixo, o script roda normalmente. Não estaria incorreto?Ou não? O aperador `::` não é apenas para métodos estáticos? Estava tentando acessar um objeto por um método estático. Mas acredito eu estar incorreto dessa forma mesmo funcionando.

```
Class Helper extends Crud
{

   public function lista($tabela)
   {
       return $this->select($tabela);
   }

}

//Uso
<?php foreach (Helper::lista('usuario') as $value):?>
  <li> <?php echo $value['usu_nome'];?></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: O que tem nessa classe `Crud`? Tem o código dela?

Comment: Métodos protecteds apenas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir da versão 5.4, é emitido erro do tipo STRICT para o caso apresentado.

Se não está vendo mensagens de erro na tela pode ser devido as configurações do reportador de erros.

Caso esteja usando PHP versão 5.4 ou superior, defina o reportador de erros para permitir reportar erros do tipo STRICT

Uma sugestão, num ambiente de desenvolvimento, é recomendável exibir todo tipo de erro e então corrigir todo tipo de problema que aparecer, mesmo os do tipo STRICT e DEPRECATED.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

A decisão sobre como configurar o reportador de erros depende de cada caso. Há casos onde é necessário ocultar erros do tipo STRICT e DEPRECATED. Um exemplo, é sistemas legados onde tornar-se inviável corrigir e converter muitos códigos. (falta de tempo, falta de investimentos, falta de permissão de um superior, etc).

Voltando ao assunto, é recomendável que corrija dentro do padrão, declarando explicitamente a visibilidade e o tipo dos métodos, tal como das propriedades de uma classe.

## Exemplo

Como NÃO fazer:

```
class Foo {
    function Bar() {

    }
}
```

Corrija definindo a visibilidade. Nesse exemplo vamos usar `public`.

```
class Foo {
    public function Bar() {

    }
}
```

O método não é estático, portanto deve ser invocado por uma instância

```
$c = new Foo;
$c->Bar();
```

Se tentar `Foo::Bar();` apresentará erros STRICT e outros erros subsequentes como o acesso ao `$this` fora de contexto, por exemplo. E isso vai causando uma bola de neve de erros.

## Driblando o reportador de erros

Conforme mencionado acima, pode haver situações onde é inviável corrigir todos os erros. Para esses casos, pode fazer a seguinte configuração

```
/*
Aqui diz que deve reportar todos os erros exceto os do tipo STRICT e DEPRECATED.
*/
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);

/*
true: para ambiente de testes (o seu localhost)
false: para ambiente de produção (o site online, no servidor)
*/
ini_set('display_errors', false);

/*
Opcionalmente pode ligar o log de erros e então definir uma local onde deseja salvar esses avisos. 
*/
ini_set('log_errors', true);
/*
Local onde serão gerados os arquivos de logs de erro.
Apenas cuidado pois dependendo da quantidade de acessos e de erros, esses arquivos podem ficar enormes. O ideal é estarem sempre vazios. Portanto, qualquer erro pequeno, sempre corrija o mais rápido possível
*/
ini_set('error_log', BASE_DIR.'..'.DS.'logs'.DS.'php'.DS.'PHP_errors-'.date('Ym').'.log');
```

## Gambiarra, invocando método não estático num método estático

```
class Foo {
    public function Bar() {

    }
    public static function Bar2() {
        $c = new Bar;
        return $c->Bar();
    }
}

Foo::Bar2();
```

O problema aqui é que não faz sentido. Está criando apenas uma faxada para tornar o código mais "elegante" e apenas consumindo memória e processamento desnecessário.

Uma solução é criar as definições de forma consistente com o objetivo final do que precisa ser usado dessa classe.

<sub>Evite gambiarras e ocultar erros do tipo STRICT e DEPRECATED. Normalmente, erros nesse nível, em curto ou médio prazo tornam-se de nível FATAL.</sub>

Comment: relamente o debug tava desligado. Deprecated: Non-static method Helper::lista() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\wamp64\www\SISGES2\system\includes\pagehome.php on line 103

Comment: aproveitando como uso um objeto dentro do estático

Comment: Editei. Leia "Driblando o reportador de erros"

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção já uso o error_log e no error_reporting uso E_ALL mas vou alterar para essa indicada obrigado.

Comment: Amigo  a intenção é que possuo um classe crud com os métodos protected  e preciso de um método externo(estático) para listar categorias do banco em varias telas do sistema e essas categorias são dinâmicas sempre sofre alterações. Então bastaria um método para listar sem precisar instanciar.

Comment: Entendo a intenção mas não faz sentido algum do ponto de vista OOP. Além do mais , classe e CRUD nada tem ver um com o outro. Mas na verdade, no final das contas estaria instanciando de qualquer forma, só que de um jeito "mascarado".  Usei o termo “fachada”  e comentei sobre  redundância e custo. Há conceitos errados e sem sentido no que vc comentou agora. Enfim, não é uma pergunta sobre design pattern, OOP ou conceitos básicos de modelagem. Mas como tocou no assunto, tive que comentar brevemente. Se quer aprender, fique a vontade para perguntar. Há vários bons profissionais que podem ensinar.

Comment: Explica o conceito errado para meu aprendizado.A classe crud contem insert, select etc abstratos.

Comment: Pesquise no site sobre esses termos ou faça novas perguntas específicas.

Answer (score 1):

Veja, como foi dito na resposta do DanielOmine, dependendo da versão do PHP, uma mensagem de erro é disparada (E_STRICT).

Isso porque, apesar de ser permitido, isso pode gerar um grave erro. É quando você tem a variável especial `$this`.

Veja:

```
    class Test{

    public function z()
    {
        return 'zzz';
    }

    public function y()
    {
        $this->y = 'yyy';

        return $this->y;
    }
}


Test::z(); // Mensagem E_STRICT

Test::y(); // Aqui vai ter um problema com `$this`
```

> Using $this when not in object context

O Operador de resolução de escopo (`::`), portanto, deve ser usado quando você for chamar métodos ou propriedades estáticas e constantes.

O PHP 5.4 oferece uma facilidade para você utilizar métodos de uma classe que seja dinâmicos com maior facilidade:

Poderia ser feito assim:

```
 foreach ((new Helper())->lista('usuario') as $value)
```

Comment: e caso precisasse usar om objeto de uma classe extendida para um método estático como usaria?

Comment: Você teria que ter a instância da classe (caso o método que deseja usar não seja estático, e sim dinâmico)